# Android - how to get json from retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am new with Retrofit,

```
 [
  {
    "scheme_name": "DSP BlackRock Tax Saver Fund (G)",
    "sch_id": "401",
    "scheme_code": "D110",
    "category_type": "Equity",
    "trxntype": "Lumpsum",
    "current_value": 570.178,
    "folio_no": "3417548/62",
    "units": 14.941,
    "trnx_date": "10-06-16",
    "current_invest": 500,
    "gainLoss": 70.18
  },
  {
    "scheme_name": "DSP BlackRock World Mining Fund  (G)",
    "sch_id": "1278",
    "scheme_code": "D341",
    "category_type": "Equity",
    "trxntype": "Lumpsum",
    "current_value": 1999.393,
    "folio_no": "3417548/62",
    "units": 302.16,
    "trnx_date": "21-07-16",
    "current_invest": 2000,
    "gainLoss": -0.61
  },
  {
    "scheme_name": "ICICI Prudential Savings Fund (G)",
    "sch_id": "119",
    "scheme_code": "P1543",
    "category_type": "Debt",
    "trxntype": "Full Redemption",
    "current_value": 0,
    "folio_no": "8349201/28",
    "units": 0,
    "trnx_date": "19-07-16",
    "current_invest": 0,
    "gainLoss": 0
  },
  {
    "scheme_name": "Kotak Emerging Equity Scheme (G)",
    "sch_id": "1001",
    "scheme_code": "K123",
    "category_type": "Equity",
    "trxntype": "Lumpsum",
    "current_value": 10309.489,
    "folio_no": "3625427/38",
    "units": 325.796,
    "trnx_date": "03-08-16",
    "current_invest": 10000,
    "gainLoss": 309.49
  }
]
```

this is json is get,

```
 package info.androidhive.retrofit.model;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import javax.annotation.Generated;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class MyTransaction {

    @SerializedName("scheme_name")
    @Expose
    private String schemeName;
    @SerializedName("sch_id")
    @Expose
    private String schId;
    @SerializedName("scheme_code")
    @Expose
    private String schemeCode;
    @SerializedName("category_type")
    @Expose
    private String categoryType;
    @SerializedName("trxntype")
    @Expose
    private String trxntype;
    @SerializedName("current_value")
    @Expose
    private Float currentValue;
    @SerializedName("folio_no")
    @Expose
    private String folioNo;
    @SerializedName("units")
    @Expose
    private Float units;
    @SerializedName("trnx_date")
    @Expose
    private String trnxDate;
    @SerializedName("current_invest")
    @Expose
    private Integer currentInvest;
    @SerializedName("gainLoss")
    @Expose
    private Float gainLoss;



    public MyTransaction(String schemeName, String schId, String schemeCode, String categoryType, String trxntype, Float currentValue, String folioNo, Float units, String trnxDate, Integer currentInvest, Float gainLoss) {
        this.schemeName = schemeName;
        this.schId = schId;
        this.schemeCode = schemeCode;
        this.categoryType = categoryType;
        this.trxntype = trxntype;
        this.currentValue = currentValue;
        this.folioNo = folioNo;
        this.units = units;
        this.trnxDate = trnxDate;
        this.currentInvest = currentInvest;
        this.gainLoss = gainLoss;
    }



    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The schemeName
     */
    public String getSchemeName() {
        return schemeName;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param schemeName
     * The scheme_name
     */
    public void setSchemeName(String schemeName) {
        this.schemeName = schemeName;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The schId
     */
    public String getSchId() {
        return schId;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param schId
     * The sch_id
     */
    public void setSchId(String schId) {
        this.schId = schId;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The schemeCode
     */
    public String getSchemeCode() {
        return schemeCode;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param schemeCode
     * The scheme_code
     */
    public void setSchemeCode(String schemeCode) {
        this.schemeCode = schemeCode;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The categoryType
     */
    public String getCategoryType() {
        return categoryType;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param categoryType
     * The category_type
     */
    public void setCategoryType(String categoryType) {
        this.categoryType = categoryType;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The trxntype
     */
    public String getTrxntype() {
        return trxntype;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param trxntype
     * The trxntype
     */
    public void setTrxntype(String trxntype) {
        this.trxntype = trxntype;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The currentValue
     */
    public Float getCurrentValue() {
        return currentValue;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param currentValue
     * The current_value
     */
    public void setCurrentValue(Float currentValue) {
        this.currentValue = currentValue;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The folioNo
     */
    public String getFolioNo() {
        return folioNo;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param folioNo
     * The folio_no
     */
    public void setFolioNo(String folioNo) {
        this.folioNo = folioNo;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The units
     */
    public Float getUnits() {
        return units;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param units
     * The units
     */
    public void setUnits(Float units) {
        this.units = units;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The trnxDate
     */
    public String getTrnxDate() {
        return trnxDate;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param trnxDate
     * The trnx_date
     */
    public void setTrnxDate(String trnxDate) {
        this.trnxDate = trnxDate;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The currentInvest
     */
    public Integer getCurrentInvest() {
        return currentInvest;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param currentInvest
     * The current_invest
     */
    public void setCurrentInvest(Integer currentInvest) {
        this.currentInvest = currentInvest;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The gainLoss
     */
    public Float getGainLoss() {
        return gainLoss;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param gainLoss
     * The gainLoss
     */
    public void setGainLoss(Float gainLoss) {
        this.gainLoss = gainLoss;
    }

}
```

Above is model class.
Api Client code

```
    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://www.mysiponline.com/admin-panel/AndroidApi/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

AIPinterfae code

```
     @POST("client_trans/{user_id}")
    Call<MyTransaction> getTransaction(@Path("user_id") String id);
```

MainActivity code

```
    Call<MyTransaction> myTransactionCall = apiService.getTransaction("420");
        myTransactionCall.enqueue(new Callback<MyTransaction>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MyTransaction> call, Response<MyTransaction> response) {

                Log.e(TAG, "Partners list : response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MyTransaction> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

In mainActivity code getting error. I am not able to get it. Please help and thanks in advance.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at info.androidhive.retrofit.activity.MainActivity$2.onResponse(MainActivity.java:65)
at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What kind of error you are getting ? Please post your logcat error along with the code which you have tried.

Comment: @GrIsHu - here is error- https://gist.github.com/Sanwal13/7d09aafeb044db8a179719e7675eb382

Comment: I also asked to post your mainactivity code also. From error only it won't give better understanding of your problem.

Comment: @GrIsHu - Here is full code - https://gist.github.com/Sanwal13/98c2dfcd0c37df3be6dcb89c05a876bf

Comment: Have you tried to debug and check whether you get the response properly parsed or not ?

Comment: Response is coming in postman, while I used in code, it get crashed.

Comment: I have checked your code an i found that you are actually not getting any kind of response from the server. Its giving Internal Server error. Make sure you are requesting for the proper data with proper parameters and authentication. Then only you will be able to get exact response from the server.

Comment: @GrIsHu - Ok, i'll check and contact you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution. Change code of AIPinterface to this

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("client_trans")
Call<List<Example>> getTransaction(@Field("user_id") String user_id);
```

Code for MainActivity to call api function

```
Call<List<MyTransaction>> listCall = apiService.getTransaction("420");
    listCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<MyTransaction>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<MyTransaction>> call, Response<List<MyTransaction>> response) {

            List<MyTransaction> examples = response.body();

            Log.e(TAG, "Response : " + response.body());// Response : null
            for (int i = 0; i < examples.size(); i++) {
                Log.e(TAG, "examples list : " + examples.get(i).categoryType);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Example>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

**You are calling single object but server is returning to you list of object.**

```
@POST("client_trans/{user_id}")
    Call<List<MyTransaction>> getTransaction(@Path("user_id") String id);
```

**edit here also**

```
 Call<List<MyTransaction>> myTransactionCall = apiService.getTransaction("420");
        myTransactionCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<MyTransaction>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<List<MyTransaction>> response) {
            if(response.code()!=200){
                  Log.d("Error",response.code()+"");
                  return;
               }
             for(MyTransaction data: response.body){
                  Log.d("Name",data.getSchemeName()+"");
                }
                Log.e(TAG, "Partners list : response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```